# Adding the same title from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to add a title from an array one by one on click event but it keeps adding the same title. Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

```
let container = document.querySelector('.container');

let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let URL = 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/';

btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    fetch(URL)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        let c = data.results.splice(0,1);
        c.forEach(a=>container.innerHTML += `<div class="title">${a.title}</div>` ); 
 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's adding the same title because you `splice` your `data.results`. If you don't do it, you will get a list of movies (I guess) and you can access it's titles.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');

let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let URL = 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/';

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fetch(URL)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      let c = data.results;
      c.forEach(a => container.innerHTML += `<div class="title">${a.title}</div>`);

    });
});
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<button>add</button>
```

Comment: Your code adds all the titles on one click and I want do add them one by one.That's why I was trying to splice original array and add spliced element to html